# How can I make scrolling image up impossible ? UIImage embed in UIScroll?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview, interface-builder

I have an image, embed in UIScroll. I don't want this image be scrolled upwards. Is it possible to implement such a thing?

P.S : OK,guys. I'v just made an uiimage behind my scroll view,that has the same color, as top part of an upper uiimageview.

Comment: kinda defeats the purpose of scrollview. I would like to say no there isn't a way unless someone says otherwise

Answer (score 1):

use UIScrollView Delegate methods

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    if(scrollView.contentOffset.y<0)
        scrollView.contentOffset =CGPointMake(0, 0);
}
```

Comment: did you set the delegate of scrollView to self. check first whether delegate method fires or not. use break point. i tested it before i posted the solution. it worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Only if the image is allowed to stand and the content can go through behind it, place the image directly on the ViewController or the parent view where is the scrollview is stored.